# IPforwarding for gateway not allowing certain software installs

Tags: openvpn, port-forwarding, router, gateway

I have a pi gateway I ultimately want to use as a VPN gateway but I'm having some issues with it being a normal gateway right now... Currently my set up is the following:

Laptop > (eth1 169.254.169.74) Pi (eth0 192.168.1.110 ) > router (192.168.1.1) > Internet

I first made my pi a static ip through /etc/network/interfaces

I then enabled ipv4 forwarding through editing /etc/sysctl.conf w/ net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

I installed iptables and clear it out with -F and then put the following: sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE

I go to my win10 laptop and go to my ethernet connection and change the gateway to 192.168.1.110 and the IP address to 169.254.169.74/255.255.0.0 with the DNS to google 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4 and it works!!!! or so it seems... I can browse the internet without any issues but any of installers like Chrome, Spotify etc that connect to the internet say No internet detected. I've been pulling my hair out the last week trying numerous iptables entries but with no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: nothing is clear at all. Check DNS. What exactly means:  I can access the internet

Comment: I can use any browser to go to any website and download any file off any website so the DNS seems to be ok. Im using 8.8.8.8 But certain installers that download off the net to install don't work like spotify and chrome installers. I just get the you don't have internet error. Almost mirrors a firewall misconfiguration but I have the firewall on the windows client disabled and I cleared out all the iptables rules on the gateway.

Comment: And port forwarding is what for? What port? On client or gateway. Do you check raw, nat, mangle tables or filter only? Openvpn what for? How its related to your client and internet access. From you question these not obvious.

Comment: Adding more clarification in the question above. Thanks for the replies gapsf.

Comment: 169.254.169.74 ([IPv4LL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link-local_address) aka APIPA) probably means the laptop expected to receive an address using DHCP but didn't . Or worse, it appears OP assigned it manually. Then using a gateway in the same network as the gateway's gateway is wrong. This gateway would tell the laptop to use the other one directly (except the lack of routable address prevents this anyway).

Comment: hmmm I assigned it manually on the laptop after checking ifconfig on the pi and seeing what the auto assign was on the pi. Is this the wrong move? Its very strange that the browser internet still works with this method just not donwloaders. Using LiveTCPUDPwatch it looks like the downloaders are only using port 80 and 443.

Comment: I didn't read correctly. I read that 169.254.169.74 was on the laptop. But the schema showed it was on the laptop. But I'm now reading it may be be on both. Never mind. I don't know how is your setup currently. I just know you should not use an address starting with 169.254 anywhere and not use an address twice.

Comment: My Pi auto assigned it to my Laptop device. I think went into adapter settings on the Laptop to assign it for the adapter and set the IP for Ip4 should I have not done that? the submask for my internal pi network is 255.255.0.0 so I thought that would be fine